# Java cannot access a protected variable in inner class

Tags: java, oop, subclass, protected

Here is my code

```
class LinkedUserList implements Iterable{
    protected LinkedListElement head = null;    /*Stores the first element of the list */
    private LinkedListElement tail = null;    /*Stores the last element of the list */
    public int size = 0;                      /* Stores the number of items in the list */

//Some methods....
//...

    public Iterator iterator() {
        return new MyIterator();
    }

    public class MyIterator implements Iterator {
        LinkedListElement current;

        public MyIterator(){
            current = this.head; //DOSEN'T WORK!!!
        }

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return current.next != null;
        }

        public User next() {
            current = current.next;
            return current.data;
        }
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("The following linked list does not support removal of items");
        }
    }
private class LinkedListElement {
    //some methods...
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have a protected variable called head, but when trying to access it from a subclass MyIterator, then it does not work, despite the variable being protected.

Why is it not working and what can i do about fixing it????

Many Thanks!!!

Comment: That is not subclass, but an inner class.

Comment: It's 2014 and you're writing non-generic code...

Comment: @Darkhogg Oh! That's like a decade since generics were introduced :)

Comment: I know, I know. Don't judge me. I would have used generics, but the way my course is structured is a bit weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` **always** refers to the current object. So, inside `MyIterator`, `this` refers to the `MyIterator` instance, not the list.

You need to use `LinkedUserList.this.head`, or simply `head`, to access the `head` member of the outer class. Note that inner classes can access private members of their outer class, so `head` doesn't need to be `protected`. It can be `private`.

Comment: protected is used to allow **subclasses** to access the member. You don't have any subclass here, only an **inner** class. A subclass is a class that would **extend** your LinkedUserList.